# Default off topic option not focused

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, off-topic, usability

When voting to close a question as off topic, the "is off topic" option is selected by default and the "vote to close" button is enabled. (I understand that there reasoning behind this, in that people are not very good at migrating questions.)

However neither the radio nor the button are focused, so you can't just hit Enter to vote, even though the screen looks as if it should work. (By comparison, once you choose "is off topic" from the initial "vote to close" screen, you can hit Enter to move to the "is off topic" screen.)