# "Enter" key should work on close vote page "Off topic" submenu

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

When closing a question, the vote dialog usually supports pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to activate the "Vote to Close" button. This is very helpful.

However, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not work in the off-topic submenu, which is somewhat irritating. (I feel that a sharp tap on my clicky  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is a much more forceful way to close a question!)

I use Firefox 19 on a Mac.

Comment: +1 for the enthusiastic closing strategy

Comment: Same problem as this guy? [Default off topic option not focused](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between *off-topic* and other close reasons is that *off-topic* has migration paths under it, so after selecting *off-topic*, you are not simply *confirming* what you've already said, but you're actually making a separate decision.

(On some Stack Exchange sites, the only migration path available is to the site's meta. But that's still a choice between closing as off-topic without any migration, and migrating somewhere.)

So the current behavior is rational and not really inconsistent--closing as *off-topic* is different because there is the added choice of whether or not to migrate and, if so, to where. One disadvantage of making <kbd>Enter</kbd> vote to close as *off-topic* right away is that it would likely lead some users to vote to close without considering fruitful migration options.

On the other hand, one benefit would be the same thing--that it would encourage users to close posts as *off-topic* without migrating them. After all, probably far too many migration votes are case, often for posts where there is no good reason to migrate them.

Another benefit would, of course, be that it would make closing quicker, *when you're closing a post as off-topic without voting to migrate it anywhere.*

I'm not sure whether or not the current behavior should be changed. For the reasons I've detailed, it's almost certainly the intended behavior.

Comment: Maybe we could leave the radio buttons in the off-topic submenu unselected, so that you have to consider a migration option...

Comment: @nneonneo I fear that, for both keyboard-shortcut-using and other users, that would have the effect of encouraging too much migration.